Finding matching versions of kafka-connect-cassandra and org.apache.kafka/connect-api
For the latest kafka-connect-cassandra source connector (kafka-connect-cassandra-8.1.14 (or kafka-connect-cassandra-8.1.15.zip)),
what is the matching org.apache.kafka/connect-api? The latest maven version (3.8.1) throws up this error.
And I can't find a matching combination of versions.
